# Effect-size for Whitney-U-test for python

Tags: python, effect-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have the following table as pandas dataframe with features feat1 and feat2:

```
testframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['feat1', 'feat2'])
testframe['feat1'] = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
testframe['feat2'] = [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

where the index is the number of observation (e.g people).

Lets assume that the features are not normally distributed, which I found out with Shapiro-Wilk test.

**I want to find out**, if there are any correlation between feat1 and feat2, so I use Mann-Whitney-U-test. As a result I get a U-Value and a p-value.
To find out more about the two features, I want to calculate the effect size. Searching for a suitable test, I found some pearson correlation value, but as far as I remember, this is only suitable for linear and and normally distributed values.

What would be a proper test for the effect size of the whitney-u test? And is there a pythonic way to implement it without many steps in between?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mann-Whitney U test is for testing whether two independent samples were selected from populations having the same distribution. It is non-parametric (meaning does not assume any distribution of your data) and compares the rank of your two groups. It says nothing about correlation.

You can use Spearman's rank correlation:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.spearmanr(testframe['feat1'], testframe['feat2'])
SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.6666666666666667, pvalue=0.03526520347507997)
```

However,I hope the test data you provided is not the real data you have. It is binary, meaning 1 and 0 only. If thats the case, you use a [jaccard index](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176613/jaccard-similarity-in-r):

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
jaccard_score(testframe['feat1'], testframe['feat2'])
```